# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'xxxx' does not provide an export named 'yyyy'

Tags: vue.js, import, snowpack

I am using Snowpack and trying to import [Chart.js for Vue](https://vue-chartjs.org/)  so I can display some data.

Getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../_snowpack/pkg/chartjs.v3.2.0.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^3.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.11",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@snowpack/plugin-dotenv": "^2.1.0",
    "@snowpack/plugin-vue": "^2.4.0",
    "snowpack": "^3.3.7"
  }
```

I refered to [Snowpack Common Errors](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/common-error-details#uncaught-syntaxerror%3A-the-requested-module-%E2%80%98.%2Fxxxxxx.js%E2%80%99-does-not-provide-an-export-named-%E2%80%98yyyyyy%E2%80%99) but solutions they offer do not help in my case or I am doing something wrong.

snowpack.config

```
/** @type {import("snowpack").SnowpackUserConfig } */
module.exports = {
    mount: {
        public: { url: '/', static: true },
        src: { url: '/dist' },
    },
    plugins: ['@snowpack/plugin-vue', '@snowpack/plugin-dotenv'],
    routes: [
        /* Enable an SPA Fallback in development: */
        // {"match": "routes", "src": ".*", "dest": "/index.html"},
    ],
    optimize: {
        /* Example: Bundle your final build: */
        // "bundle": true,
    },
    packageOptions: {
        namedExports: ['vue-chartjs', 'chart.js'],
    },
    devOptions: {
        /* ... */
    },
    buildOptions: {
        /* ... */
    },
};
```

Chart.js

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'GitHub Commits',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

Can anyone has any idea for a workaround?

Comment: I landed up dropping Snowpack and using Nuxt.js. Most likely the problem was on the integration side between ChartJS and Vue 3.